# Objectify 5 to connect the local datastore emulator in java project

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify, local-database

I have to connect java appengine project with local datastore emulator in gcp.

```
ObjectifyService.init(new ObjectifyFactory(
    DatastoreOptions.newBuilder()
        .setHost("http://localhost:8484")
        .setProjectId("my-project")
        .build()
        .getService()
));
```

The above solution applies to Objectify v6, I want a way to connect datastore emulator to the java appengine Project in Objectify v5 ?

Comment: can i get to know which sdk you are using, is it GCP Datastore SDK or the App Engine SDK’s Datastore bindings?

Comment: The below results of the command "gcloud version"  in my machine

`Google Cloud SDK 351.0.0`
`app-engine-java 1.9.90`
`app-engine-python 1.9.93`
`beta 2021.07.30`
`bq 2.0.70`
`cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0`
`core 2021.07.30`
`gsutil 4.66`